# How does Django handles Model Meta ordering in Database

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

On ordering Django documentation [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#ordering)

> The default ordering for the object, for use when **obtaining** lists of objects

What does it means by obtaining? Does Django stores objects normally and while fetching use something like `ORDER BY` (e.g. in SQL)? Or does data is stored in particular order? Or indexing takes place on ordering column ?

Objective is to understand how costly is insert/fetch operation on Django model with Meta ordering as compared to one which hasn't.

Comment: lol! seems like today I have asked almost the same question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064572/orm-ordering-vs-model-meta-ordering-django-1-11

Answer (score 1):

When **obtaining** means when the query is executed so when fetching using `ORDER BY`.